# Approximating By Compactly Supported Functions in Weak Convergence Arguements

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm working on the following question. I'm having trouble with the solution presented in the textbook - specifically weak convergence.

> Let $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^N), 1<p<\infty$ with $\alpha>0$ real, define $f_n = n^\alpha f(nx)$ for $n = 1,2,3,\dots$. Does $\{f_n\}$ strongly converge? Does it weakly converge?

It can be shown that for $\alpha < N/p$ the sequence strongly converges, otherwise it does not strongly converge. Clearly, for $\alpha < N/p$ the sequence also weakly converges (I got this far). Now consider $\alpha = N/p$. **Suppose $f$ vanishes for $|x| >K$...(some analysis to conclude weak convergence). For $f$ arbitrary, given $\epsilon > 0$ and $\phi \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$, let $g$ be a function vanishing outside a compact set such that $\|f-g\|_p \leq \epsilon/2\|\phi\|_q$.**

1. Why do they consider $f$ compact first?
2. How do we get that estimate between $f$ and the compactly supported $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want $\mathbb{R}^N$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^d$, so your later $N/p$ makes sense.

1. The analysis that you omitted should tell you why.  Essentially when $f$ is compactly supported, eventually $f_n$ lives inside a very small ball centered 0 so you can estimate the integrals by turning the condition onto your $\phi\in L^q$, i.e., $\lvert\int\phi f_n\rvert\leq \lVert f_n\rVert_p\cdot\lVert \phi 1_{\lvert x\rvert<K/n}\rVert_q\to 0$.
2. Consider $g_R=f\cdot 1_{|x|<R}$.  As $R\to\infty$ we have $g_R\to f$ in $L^p$ so there is an $R$ where $\lVert f-g\rVert_p$ satisfies this estimate.

Comment: yes I did mean $N$ not $d$ -- thanks!